# How to use meek with Tor expert bundle?

Tags: windows, bridge, meek

I have setup the Tor browser bundle to use meek/bridges, etc... But I am trying to also use meek with the Tor expert bundle (Tor as as service) and I have no idea how to, I have Google and searched this to death. So I post it here in the hopes that someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

torproject.org should be your first go to place. Here's the page for [meek](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek). I found this from on the page for [bridges](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en#Understanding) on the main [documentation](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/documentation) page.

Honestly, reading through this documentation, it looks like this is not a task for a beginners and it is also not free because you will need to buy your own cloud service from Amazon or Azure instead of using Tor's. My suggestion would be to ask this question on the [tor-talk mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo) to see if there exists an updated guide for Tor expert bundle that uses Tor's existing meek bridges.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **GUI** for tor expert bundle & use **Meek** on the settings:

https://github.com/abysshint/tor-control-panel

Answer (score 0):

Just in 3 steps! They are:

- **Obtain the transport proxy** - go to the proxy's site and download it, or you can try taking a binary out of the Tor Browser Bundle, it also works ;) But I do recommend you to build the last version from source if you know how to do it - it will give you many benefits including speed
- **Point Tor to the proxy binary** - just add to your `torrc` config a line like this `ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4 exec c:\\Tor\\pt\\obfs4proxy.exe` or for Linux/Unix `ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4 exec /opt/tor/obfs4proxy`. It will tell Tor that the transports that are listed *without space, just comma separated* in a first argument are served by the proxy binary with the second argument. The proxy binary's path must be **strictly** absolute, also pay attention if you're using a chroot environments in Unix or Linux! The obfs line was from my actual working configs to illustrate you how to use multiple transports, put just `meek` for a first argument in your case.
- **Add a bridge with your transport** - add `bridge meek ...` line to your config *after* defining the transport handler, and enjoy!